# Необходимо сделать строку в таблице ссылкой

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap

Использую CSS фрэймворк Bootstrap. Необходимо сделать строку в таблице, ссылкой:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>…</th>
          <th>…</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr> <<< - ссылка 1
          <td>…</td>
          <td>…</td>
        </tr>
        <tr> <<< - ссылка 2
          <td>…</td>
          <td>…</td>
        </tr>   
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Очень информативно...

Comment: А что тут лишнего писать, перепробовал различные методы не получаеться.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если в строке только одна ячейка, то справиться можно и простым цсс, поставив ссылке display:block, тогда она займет все отведенное ей в строке пространство и в любом месте строки будет ссылка, но если в строке несколько ячеек, то без яваскрипта не обойтись

```
<tr onclick="window.location.href='/somePage'; return false"></tr>
```

Comment: Вариант рабочий, но в нём не устраивает то что визуально при наведении на ячейку она не являеться ссылкой (не отображаеться путь перехода и указатель мышки не в виде руки)

Comment: странно, про bootstrap.css слышали, а про 
tr {cursor:pointer} нет?

Comment: Жуть. Нормального контекстного меню для ссылки не будет.

Answer (score 3):

Если уж очень хочется изощриться не используя JavaScript, например для SEO. 
Как вариант:

```
<table class="table" style="position: relative;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="#" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; left: 0px; height: 1.5em;"></a>
            ...
        </td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Но я бы использовал решение на JavaScript, т.к. не известно как поведет себя данный пример в разных браузерах (тестил на FireFox 29.0).

Comment: но с динамикой или разношёрстным контентом будут большие заморочки! см. https://jsfiddle.net/v2qe3twu/1/

Answer (score 1):

```css
.table { display:table }
.table > * { display:table-row-group }
.table > header { display:table-header-group }
.table > * > * { display:table-row; }
.table > * > * > * { display:table-cell; }

.tbl {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: .5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="table tbl">
  <header>
    <div>
      <div>Header 1</div>
      <div>Header 2</div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div>
    <a href="//ya.ru">
      <div>Cell 1</div>
      <div>Cell 2</div>
    </a>
    <a href="//ya.ru">
      <div>67 5 6 34 8hjk g rr76</div>
      <div>67 5 6 34 8hjk g rr76</div>
    </a>   
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

Так в чем проблема то?

```
<a href="#">
<tr> 
      <td>…</td>
      <td>…</td>
</tr>
</a>
```

Comment: буэ...

уж лучше Jquery использовать.

Comment: Особенно, если посмотреть на теги, то понятно, что jquery человек не хочет, да? И зачем тянуть библиотеку, когда все делается средствами html?

Comment: Такая конструкция не работает, уже пробовал. Напоминаю что использую bootstrap
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html

Comment: <tr> 
      <td><a href="#">…</a></td>
      <td><a href="#">…</a></td>
      </tr>
>

Comment: Проблема в том, что это не работает: https://jsfiddle.net/v8j0d8n2/